# How to play a wav file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, audio, wav, ruby-1.9.3

What is a good way to play an audio file from Ruby that is wav format?

OSX or Ubuntu...

Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: What have you tried? A quick search with Google shows a number of hits; What did you find when you looked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used [Gosu](https://github.com/jlnr/gosu) to play audio in a simple game context, so I imagine it would work fine for you...

```
@tune = Gosu::Song.new(window, "tune.wav")
@tune.play(true)
```

Comment: What is `window`? I get `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'window' for main:Object`.

Comment: Read [the documentation](http://www.libgosu.org/rdoc/Gosu/Song.html)... it's looking for a `Gosu::Window` there. The window of course doesn't need to be drawn.

Comment: in windows, it sounds weird.

Comment: @abigoroth open an issue on GitHub and talk about it.